# SQL Error -4903 when trying to connect to DB2 database

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015, db2

I am getting an SQL error code of -4903 when trying to connect to a DB2 database using SQC code (this is an ANSI C application so I need to use SQC for SQL queries). When I look at IBM's website to see what a -4903 means, all it says is "The length of parameter n of function name is not valid". However I have no idea which parameter or function it is referring to. I have tried looking at the SQLCA objects members, but I am unable to see them in Visual Studio 2015.

This is an ANSI C application debugging in Visual Studio 2015. I am able to connect to the same database using a DB2 command prompt (i.e, by running "db2 connect to dbname user username using password". However when I try to do this in code I get the -4903 error. I have also tried this on two different OS's, Windows 7 and Windows 10. I have colleagues who have had no trouble doing this on a Windows 7 machine.

```
while ((retry++ < 3)
        || (sqlca.sqlcode == -30080)
        || (sqlca.sqlcode == -900  ) )
    {
        EXEC SQL CONNECT TO :DBName USER :userid USING :pword;

        if ((SQLCODE == 0 ) || (SQLCODE == (-1026)))
        {
            return(1);
        }
        else
        {
            dbLogAudit(KLCB, PLCB, KLLOGSEV(T),
                "Retry DBInit/sqlca.sqlcode : %i", sqlca.sqlcode);
        }
    }
```

I expect the SQLCODE to be 0, which indicates a successful connection, and for the function to return 1 to it's caller. But instead the sqlca.sqlcode variable is -4903 (which I described above).

EDIT: I found the parameters being passed into the error message. The full error text is "The length of parameter runtime_pid of function sqlastrt_trusted is not valid".

Comment: If there are colleagues where the same executable-program is *working correctly* while on at least one workstation that executable is failing, then you have an environmental difference. It's your job to find what the differences between the working and failing environments might be, for example the exact fixpack of the Db2-client, or its configuration/setup/or the user-setting, or the executable program is in fact different between the working and failing environments.  There may be more details in the client-side diagnostics file. You can also trace the CLI on the client .

Comment: So I found the error message, if it helps. See the above edit. I tried to enable a trace on the client but ran into some trouble, will continue trying.

Comment: Prove that the CLI libraries are identical (in version + fixpack + bitness + dll file sizes ) between the working and failing environments, especially if you are connecting to either z/OS or i-series.

Comment: Do you know the best way to do that? I apologize, I am very new to DB2, as are most of the developers at my company. I did find this article https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.cobol/fRLcg4XLjF0 and the last response leads me to believe that it is an issue with the versions between development and runtime being different

Comment: if you have a working Win7 , and a failing Win7 (for the same binary), compare the output of the `db2level` command (if it exists) else compare the contents of the directory tree containing the Db2 client product (example location c:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB ) but your locations may differ.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own issue. Thanks to Mao for the help on debugging this one.

My development environment for DB2 was running version 8.1.0, which uses 162 bytes for the struct called "sqla_program_id". However, the runtime environment, which uses 292 bytes for that same struct, was version 10.5. Once I upgraded my development DB2 instance to v10.5 it worked like a charm.